# How to add print methods on JPanel

Tags: java

How can I add a print method on a JPanel object?

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class PlaceOrder extends JFrame{

    private JButton PlaceOrderButton;
    private ProductsDatabase Database;

    public PlaceOrder(){
        super("Please fill in your data:");

        ProductsDatabase Database = new ProductsDatabase();
        Database.FillDatabase();

        PlaceOrderButton = new JButton("Place Order");

        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();

        mainPanel.setLocation(8, 3);
        mainPanel.add(new JLabel("Products"));
        //I want to add a print method here//
        mainPanel.add(PlaceOrderButton);

        this.setContentPane(mainPanel);
        this.pack();
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

I want to add a method that prints the products that are added in ProductsDatabase.

Comment: By "prints", I assume you mean prints to a printer rather than prints to a screen? If so, have a look through this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/printing/

Comment: Did you read this? [Printing swing components](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/printing/swing.html)

Comment: I think I have not made myself clear and I am sorry for this.I want the list of products to be printed on screen like on this picture(http://prntscr.com/28ewkz).I have added the products in the Database.I have also created a print method in the ProductsDatabase class that prints the products name and the products price.